# split a string of binary numbers and store it an array of type int in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to split a string of binary numbers for example "0101011010" and store it in int array. Should be done in c++.

This is what i have tried.

```
 istringstream buffer(inputstring);
    int inp;
    buffer >> inp; 
    int a[10];
    int i=0;
    while(inp>=0){

       if(inp==0){
           a[i]=0;
         break;
      }
       else{
           int value = inp%10;
           a[i]=value;
           inp=inp/10;
      }; 
      i++
    }
```

The problem with this is, if the string contains "0" in the beginning, it is missed out when it gets converted to int.

Comment: You're doing it in an overly-complicated way. Ditch the `istringstream` and just loop through the characters in the original string. If it's a `'0'` put a zero into the corresponding array element; if a `'1'`, put a one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this pushing into a `vector` of `int`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input="0101011010";
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
    {v.push_back(input[i]-'0');}
}
```

But if you really want to use an array you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input="0101011010";
    int arr[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {arr[i]=input[i]-'0';}
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {cout << arr[i] << endl;}
}
```

Comment: What does -'0' do?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(inp>=0){
   if(inp==0){
     a[i]=0;
     break;
  }
  //...
}
```

If the input is zero, neither `i` gets incremented, nor the input is changed, so you run into an infinit loop. Try modifying `input` and `i` in the `if`-part also.

/Edit: ok your way of doing this is really over-complicated. I am not a big friend of copy&paste code but here is the way I would do it:

```
std::string str;
std::vector<int> number;
buffer >> str;  //Read the value into a string
for(char c : str) //Loop over all characters in the string
    number.push_back(c == '1' ? 1 : 0); //Write zero or one depending on character
```